# XBox 360 Wireless Controller not working with Kodi / XBMC

Tags: xbox360, xbmc, kodi

**System:**

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (kernel: 3.13.0-45-generic)
- Kodi (14.2-BETA1 Git:2259d0b). Platform: Linux x86 64-bit
- Original XBOX 360 wireless controller with Xbox 360 USB Wireless Adapter

**What I did:**

Install `ubuntu-xboxdrv`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv
```

**Tested if it works with:**

- jstest: YES
- sdl-jstest: YES
- retroarch and mupen64plus playing N64 Mario Kart: YES
- **Kodi: NOOOO ????**

I enabled extensive logging for kodi and uploaded a logfile here: http://xbmclogs.com/psky8dtse (until 20. March '15)

Kodi does not detect the joystick even though it is available over SDL and `/dev/input/js0`

**UPDATE:** Running Kodi as root fixes the problem. So it seems there are permission issues. Still don't know how to fix this...

**UPDATE2 / FIX:** I wrote a NodeJS-bridge between Kodi and the Xbox Controller: https://github.com/cgrossde/XboxControllerKodiBridge
This way only the Bridge needs to run as root and Kodi can continue to run as an unprivileged user. It includes an upstart script that it starts/stops with Kodi.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the unprivileged user to group "input" (see /etc/group), as "/dev/input" uses this group.